# Shortening a long vector in R

Tags: r, string, vector

Vectors `a` and `b` can be shortened using `toString(width = 10)` in Base R resulting in a shorter vector that ends in `....`

However, I wonder how I can make the shortened vector to end in `..., last vector element`?

My `desired_output` is shown below.

```
a <- 1:26
b <- LETTERS  

toString(a, width = 10)
# [1] "1,2,...."
desired_output1 = "1,2,...,26"

toString(b, width = 10)
# [1] "A,B,...."
desired_output2 = "A,B,...,Z"
```

Comment: For future clarity, what was the use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After applting the `toString`, we may use `sub` to remove the substring to `format`

```
f1 <- function(vec, n = 2) { 
   
    gsub("\\s+", "", 
     sub(sprintf("^(([^,]+, ){%s}).*, ([^,]+)$", n), "\\1...,\\3", toString(vec)))

}
```

-testing

```
> f1(a)
[1] "1,2,...,26"
> f1(b)
[1] "A,B,...,Z"
> f1(a, 3)
[1] "1,2,3,...,26"
> f1(b, 3)
[1] "A,B,C,...,Z"
> f1(a, 4)
[1] "1,2,3,4,...,26"
> f1(b, 4)
[1] "A,B,C,D,...,Z"
```

Comment: @SimonHarmel looks like it is already answered

Comment: A [question of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70793697/16762740).

Answer (score 6):

You could just add the end on.

```
paste(toString(a, width = 10), a[length(a)], sep=", ")  
[1] "1, 2, ...., 26"
paste(toString(b, width = 10), b[length(b)], sep=", ")  
[1] "A, B, ...., Z"
```

Answer (score 2):

We could do it this way:
Creating a function that extraxt the first two elements and the last element of the vector and paste them together:

```
my_func <- function(x) {
  a <- paste(x[1:2], collapse=",")
  b <- tail(x, n=1)
  paste0(a,",...,",b)
}

my_func(a)
[1] "1,2,...,26"

my_func(b)
[1] "A,B,...,Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(stringr)

a <- 1:26
b <- LETTERS  


reduce_string <- function(x, n_show) {
    
    str_c(x[1:n_show], collapse = ',') %>% 
        str_c('....,', x[[length(x)]])
    
}

reduce_string(a, 2)
#> [1] "1,2....,26"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>