# rbind/bind_rows two unequal data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, rbind

Below, I wonder how to `rbind` `dat2` to `dat1` such that I can achieve my `Desired_output` below?

*Note that no new columns has to be added. (see the desired output)*

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

dat1 <- as.data.frame(coef(summary(fit)))

dat2 <- data.frame(Estimate = 2, pr = 0.1234567901, row.names = "Q")

Desired_output =
"
               Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 30.09886054  1.6339210 18.421246 6.642736e-18
hp          -0.06822828  0.0101193 -6.742389 1.787835e-07
Q            2.00000000         NA        NA 0.1234567901
"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution, which requires `names(dat2)[2] <- names(dat1)[4]` before binding the rows (there was a mismatch of column names):

```r
library(tidyverse)

fit <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

dat1 <- as.data.frame(coef(summary(fit)))

dat2 <- data.frame(Estimate = 2, pr = 0.1234567901, row.names = "Q")

names(dat2)[2] <- names(dat1)[4] # <--- This is CRUCIAL

dat1 %>% 
  bind_rows(dat2)

#>                Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) 30.09886054  1.6339210 18.421246 6.642736e-18
#> hp          -0.06822828  0.0101193 -6.742389 1.787835e-07
#> Q            2.00000000         NA        NA 1.234568e-01
```

Comment: You are right, @SimonHarmel. That had escaped to me... Let me try further.

Comment: OK, @SimonHarmel.

Comment: Just do as I say in my edited solution, @SimonHarmel.

Comment: Thank you, would you please tell me how the "critical" line works, because this is just a toy example, and I want to apply this other examples and may need to change this. Thanks.

Comment: To `bind_col` work without creating additional columns, the colnames of the binding data.frames _**must**_ be the same. Since you used `pr` instead of `Pr(>|t|)`, there was a mismatch of colnames and, therefore, a new column was added. With `names(dat2)[2] <- names(dat1)[4]`, the two colnames become equal! Was I enough clear, @SimonHarmel?

Answer (score 0):

In base R:

```
rbind(dat1, Q = list(dat2[1], NA, NA, dat2[2]))

               Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    30.09886  1.6339210 18.421246 6.642736e-18
hp          -0.06822828  0.0101193 -6.742389 1.787835e-07
Q                     2         NA        NA    0.1234568
```